# How to find string matches between a text file and CSV?

Tags: python-2.7, csv, string-matching

I am currently working with Python 2.7 on a stand alone system. My preferred method for solving this problem would be to use pandas data-frames to compare. However, I do not have access to install the library on the system I'm working with. So my question is how else could I use a text file and look for matches of the strings in a csv.

If I have a main csv file with many fields (for relevance the first one is timestamps) and several other text files that contain a list of timestamps how can I compare each of the txt files with the main csv and if a match is found grab the entire row from the csv based on the specific field matching and outputting that result to another csv

Example:

example.csv

```
timestamp,otherfield,otherfield2
1.2345,,
2.3456,,
3.4567,,
5.7867,,
8.3654,,
12.3434,,
32.4355,,
```

example1.txt

```
2.3456
3.4565
```

example2.txt

```
12.3434
32.4355
```

If there are any questions I'm happy to answer them.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have code showing your attempt? What would the sample output look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can load all the files into lists, then search the lists using

```
with open('example.txt','r') as file_handle:
    example_file_content = file_handle.read().split("\n")

with open("example1.txt", "r") as file_handle:  
    example1_file_content = file_handle.read().split("\n")

for index, line in enumerate(example_file_content):
    if line.split(",")[0] in example1_file_content:
        print('match found; line is',line)
```